# attribute routing based on different roles in mvc5?

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-5.2

`[Route("{page:regex(^(?!admin$))}/home/Index")]

[Route("Admin/home/Index")]

public Actionresult index()
{..}`

I have two types of logins; if I login as an admin I should get admin/home/index.  If login as client I should get home/index. Is it possible to get different url at different login?

Comment: You can handle this redirecting in the `Login` action method based on the roles.

Comment: try it on login action